# Android PreferenceScreen overlay Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, preference, preferencescreen

Android PreferenceScreen overlay Toolbar.
I have tried to use padding and margin to set Preference Screen under the
Toolbar but no any success.

NOTE: after changing Toolbar with ActionBar it works as expected.

Any help please.

Thanks,
Hrach

Comment: Please post any screenshots / xml codes so we get better understanding

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. I have already resolved the issue and post it also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just now resolve the issue:

Here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/app_toolbar"
             android:id="@+id/app_toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/pref_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/app_toolbar" />

        <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

After adding the fist FrameLayout the issue is resolved.

Thanks